# Is there a single, non crude word for "had sex"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are many words for "had sex", such as the F-word, "banged", "screwed" etc.

None of these are formal words, and I'm wondering if there is a single word for "had sex" that is more appropriate than the aforementioned?

Comment: Do you mean [coitus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coitus)?

Comment: @HotLicks is coitus it's own past tense? Would it be "coitused"? I normally go for that, but I'm not convinced it's valid there. "They coitus" does not sound right, and I'd like to replace the word "banged" in this sentence: "Jack said they banged". "Had sex" goes there, but I'd like one word.

Comment: It's a noun, not a verb.

Comment: @HotLicks is there any verb that's not especially crude?

Comment: The normal decorous euphemism would be *made love*.

Comment: You could always say "intercoursed".  Would make purists gag, though.

Comment: Would "bonked" be considered "crude"?

Comment: Between two consenting adults, **fornicate**... the Bible has ***know***, as in "Adam *knew* Eve his wife." https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/know_someone_in_the_biblical_sense

Comment: @Andrew yeah I think so

Comment: @Mari-LouA equally laid may be valid?

Comment: @Tim does it have to be a verb?  You can say they were *physical*, which implies sex happened.  Or *intimate*.

Comment: @Andrew both of those work, although don't make it clear that it's intercourse rather than making out etc.

Comment: Here are a few 'nice' ones you might use for gossip with a friend that aren't quite as crude and suggesting more 'mutual' entertainment:  "hanky-panky",  "got naked",  "getting busy"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would probably go for "copulated".

**[copulate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/copulate)**

> to engage in sexual intercourse

merriam-webster.com

Comment: Hello Peter. I edited your answer to include definition, source, and citation: things we consider very important for a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

The least-salacious verb I can think of is ***mated***:

> Mate *(verb, intransitive)*:  to copulate
>    <sub>from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mate)</sub>

Comment: Sounds a bit like a wildlife documentary, but it's a valid word.

Answer (score 3):

**Congressing**, though it is perhaps less common:

> 7. coitus; sexual intercourse.
>      (from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/congressing))

Merriam-Webster's online dictionary redirects automatically to **coitus**:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congressing

Comment: I _knew_ Congress was doing _something_.

Comment: +1 for coitus, but it's more often than not it's ["have coitus"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUmMGvujZZ8)